# Unity send SMS message

Tags: sms, unity-game-engine, messaging, openurl

I'm currently using Unity for developing an application for Android and IOS and I'm able to use the function: `Application.OpenURL("mailto:" + email_address + "?subject=Email&body=msg from Unity");`

to send emails from within my application, and I know you can use a similar function to open up the mobile devices SMS system however I'm unsure on how to actually go about this.

If anyone can please advise how I can open up the native SMS system through "Application.OpenURL()" that'd be fantastic. I'm also open to using an alternative solution if anyone's aware.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the etcetera plugin from Prime31. I use it for email composition on iOS but it's available for Android as well.

Comment: Thanks Kay, yeah I actually ended up using the Prime31 Etcetera plugin as I needed to use some of the other features included. Works a treat :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variety of OpenURL commands to open up numerous apps in iOS. Android has a comparable nomenclature too. Of course I don't know if below will work in Android but it's worth a shot.

```
       var sms_number : String = "+17032129831"
       Application.OpenURL("sms:" + sms_number);
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, just tested that out and it seemed to work which is great :). Although I've now gone with the Prime 31 Etcetera plugin as I needed some of the other functionality included in the plugin, however it's good to know this works too :).