# Send SMS by application.openurl

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, sms

I am stuck in this small Unity/iOS problem, could you please help!
Do you know how to send SMS by application.openurl, with the SMS has a link in http on iOS?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide some of your code or some information of your research?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948412/unity-send-sms-message

Comment: Hi Bhumit,
I mean with the SMS has contents which already be filled.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: With openurl you can only send mobile number not message, try to use `MFMessageComposeViewController`